# shell: Retrieve the path of files copied by Finder

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, zsh, clipboard

I want to get the path of files copied by Finder in my zsh script. I don't mind calling an external utility/script.

I have tried `pbpaste`, it just returns the basename of one of the copied files.

PS: The files are copied using cmd+c, by hand, in Finder.

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of the applescript and zsh script? Right now we can only guess. I would guess that you used something like `move [...] to folder`, so you would have to add something like `set the clipboard to folder` before being able to use `pbpaste`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy full file paths to the clipboard in *Finder* using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

However, there are other situations where retrieving files off the clipboard are needed.  The piece of AppleScript below will retrieve the set of files last copied to the clipboard using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in *Finder*.  Initially, it retrieves the file objects themselves, which can be used in all sorts of ways in AppleScript.  However, the last half of the script converts the file objects to a straightforward list of posix file paths, then concatenates it into a string delimited by a linefeed.

```
use framework "AppKit"

property this : a reference to current application
property NSPasteboard : a reference to NSPasteboard of this
property NSURL : a reference to NSURL of this

property text item delimiters : linefeed

set pb to NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
set fs to (pb's readObjectsForClasses:[NSURL] options:[]) as list

repeat with f in fs
    set f's contents to POSIX path of f
end repeat

fs as text
```

To implement this in `zsh`, you can use `osascript` like so:

```
osascript -e "use framework \"AppKit\"

property this : a reference to current application
property NSPasteboard ..."
```

Or you can save the AppleScript as a file using *Script Editor* with either extension `.scpt` (compiled code) or `.applescript` (text), then run it from the command-line like this:

```
osascript /path/to/file.applescript
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code concerning the copied Finder items, it is difficult to give an exact solution for you.  Here is one possible solution.  This following AppleScript code will take the currently selected finder items and will set the clipboard to the full file paths of those selected finder items, as a list.

```
tell application "Finder" to set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
if selectedFiles is {} then return
set filePaths to {}
repeat with thisFile in selectedFiles
    set end of filePaths to POSIX path of thisFile
end repeat
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to (filePaths as text)
```

**OR**

Since your process is to copy the selected finder files to your clipboard using the keyboard shortcut cmd + c,  you can use this following AppleScript code in Automator.app and save it as a service.  In the System Preferences.app you can then assign a keyboard shortcut to your new service.

Before using the keyboard shortcut cmd + c to copy your Finder items, you would run the service you just created, to store the file paths so you can retrieve them later.

In short, this AppleScript code will display a dialog, giving you two options.

1) Write the file paths of the currently selected finder files to a temporary text file ( which can be retrieved when you need them)

2) Set the clipboard to the file paths by retrieving that information from the temp file

```
tell application "Finder" to set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
if selectedFiles is {} then return
set filePaths to {}
repeat with thisFile in selectedFiles
    set end of filePaths to POSIX path of thisFile
end repeat
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set filePaths to (filePaths as text)

set readOrWrite to {"Write Selected Files' File Path To Temp", "Set Clipboard To The File Paths"}

activate
set theChoice to (choose from list readOrWrite ¬
    with title "CHOOSE YOUR OPTION PLEASE" with prompt ¬
    "Write File Paths Or Set Clipboard To File Paths?" default items 1 ¬
    OK button name "DO IT" cancel button name "Cancel") as string

if theChoice is "Write Selected Files' File Path To Temp" then
    writeToFile(filePaths)
else if theChoice is "Set Clipboard To The File Paths" then
    readFile()
else
    return
end if


on writeToFile(filePaths)
    set theFile to "/tmp/File_Paths.txt"
    set theText to filePaths
    try
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        set eof writeToFile to 0
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access theFile
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        set eof writeToFile to 0
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    end try
end writeToFile

on readFile()
    set theFile to "/tmp/File_Paths.txt"
    set the clipboard to (read theFile)
end readFile
```

[image]

[image]

After storing the file path information, then you would copy your finder items using shortcut cmd + c,  do whatever you want with the copied finder files.

Then go back and run the service again to copy the file paths to your clipboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can use this to solve my use case now, but this doesn't answer the question. I want to get the path of files already copied in Finder, not selected. And I am just going to give the paths to another function which will convert PSD files to PNG. Something like `cpsd "$(paste-paths)"`.

Comment: That's my point. Without seeing your code, it's difficult to supply an exact answer.  How are you copying the finder files? As a manual process? Selecting them in finder and keyboard shortcut to copy?

Comment: Yeah, exactly :)) I just select files in Finder and do cmd+c. On a sidenote, your applescript gives me "execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)".

Comment: Are you aware that option + cmd + c  .. as a keyboard shortcut for selected Finder items, Will copy the full pathnames?

Comment: I wasn't aware (I knew it, but no, not aware :D), but I still like to have an answer to my question.

Comment: I didn’t get a notification for your edit. Thank you for your efforts. I appreciate it. 